# @valid annotation not validating the input in spring mvc

Tags: spring, validation, model-view-controller, bean-validation

I am trying to the implement Spring mvc validation using java validation api & hibernate validator but somehow the code is not validating the input. The BindingResult object doesn't contain any errors.

I followed this tutorial for this : https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

Below is the Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processRegistration( @javax.validation.Valid User user,BindingResult errors, Model model) {
    if(errors.hasErrors()){
        model.addAttribute(errors);
        return "register";
    }
    System.out.println("Saving user..user.getUsername()");
    return "redirect:/user/"+user.getUsername();
}
```

Below is the object that needs validation:

```
public class User {
  @NotEmpty
  @Size(min=5, max=15)
  String firstName;
  @NotEmpty
  @Size(min=5, max=15)
  String lastName;
  @NotEmpty
  @Size(min=5, max=15)
  String username;
  @NotEmpty
  @Size(min=5, max=15)  
  String password;
  .....
}
```

Dispacther servlet :

```
public class AppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Class<?>[]{main.config.RootConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{main.config.WebConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}
```

}

I have two validation jars in build path

[image: Jar file screenshots]

But still the validation is not happening. Can you tell me why?

Comment: The fact that it is in your build path doesn't mean it is in your runtime path. Use something like maven or gradle to manage your dependencies instead of hunting for yourself. Make sure you use one of the supported hibernate validator versions. And you should add `@ModelAttribute` next to the `@Valid` annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this issue by updating the hibernate-validator jar to hibernate-validator-4.2.0.Final and also added SLF4J jar version slf4j.api-1.6.1.

Now I am able to get the errors in BindingResult object.